# How to convert finger print format to byte in java?

Tags: java, fingerprint

How to convert finger print format (fpf) to byte in java?

Comment: Huh?  Google does not seem to turn up anything related to fingerprints for 'fpf'.

Answer (score 1):

The general way to get a resource such as a File, or URL pointing to the net or an application resource, is to establish an InputStream to the object of interest, then read the input stream.

See the [Basic I/O Lesson](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) of the Java Tutorial for more details.

Comment: fingerprint images are in different format.can you know how to convert that format to byte.